# Transformations 3D in CSS3 div doesn't shows up

Tags: html, css

I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.html5-css3.fr/css3/transformations-3d-css3)  to make some transformations in 3D.

Here you can find a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4KS6/1/).

Why is only the red div getting displayed, but the green div not?

HTML:

```
<div id="scene3D">
  <div id="flip">
    <div>Red Text</div>
    <div>Green Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#scene3D{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-perspective:500px;   
  perspective:500px;   
}
#flip{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition:all 1s ease;
}
#scene3D:hover #flip{

  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
#flip div{
  position:absolute;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:red;     
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;     
  backface-visibility: hidden;   
}
#flip div:last-child{
  background:green;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); 
  transform: rotateX(180deg); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property that you didn't set, and that is needed: transform-style: preserve-3d.

```
#flip{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transition:all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

backface-visibility: hidden makes the element not visible when it is reversed.

But, if you don't set the preserve-3d, that works only with the transforms to the element itself.

That's why the green element doesn't show, but the red one keeps shown (it shouldn't !)

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4KS6/2/)

Comment: it's work with `transform-style: preserve-3d;` thanks a lot @vals

Answer (score 1):

You have hidden `backface-visibility: hidden;` for showing green div `backface-visibility: visible;` you have to define it to visible.

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/nu69Y/

Hope it helps you!

Comment: It helps thanks a lot @Harish but there a problem. The color change even before the div rotate totally.

Comment: yeah, as we hover element visible if you want after flipping try transition delay http://bit.ly/1jPQic7 this could help you how to delay transition